# Can't return value from function?

Tags: c++, return-value

I wrote this code and there is a problem that I can't seem to work out. The function is supposed to return T1 and cout it from the main but it always gives me an error "T1 is undeclared identifier". Why?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;
double factorial()
{
   int i;
   double T1,total=0;
   for(i=0;i<200;i++) 
   {
      clock_t start = clock();

      int a,N,f;
  N=99999;
      f=N;
  for(a=N-1;a>0;a--)
  {
         f=f*a;
      }

      clock_t end = clock();
      T1=double(end-start)/(double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
      total=total+T1;
   }
   T1=total/200;
   return T1;
}
int main()
{
   factorial();
   cout<<T1<<endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define `T1` first locally or make it a global variable (not recommended).

```
int main()
{
double T1=factorial();

cout<<T1<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: it runs but gives a wrong answer, it gives 0,, I used double instead of int it gives a totally different answer , its supposed to be 0.00116 but it givs 0.00177

Comment: @Anon: Why is 0 a wrong answer? Your computer is pretty fast, you've only done a few thousand multiplications. Or, the compiler simply optimised them out completely.

Comment: That should be an issue with your `factorial()` function. Your question was about compile error which sounds like got fixed with the above code.

Comment: no no it gave out zero cz i used int instead of double, but the question is ,, is the answer supposed to be fluctating

Comment: yes it will fluctuate -- since you are using clock(), it will have slightly different times for each execution.  These can be very different times if your computer is really busy doing other things.

Comment: You should tag this as the answer (you will gain rep and people will be more likely to help you in the future). CoolBeans was the first to answer and I would let the "int" mistake/typo slide... as long as he upvotes me :-).

Comment: I bumped him as much as I could -- seems like a cool guy.  It didn't give him the rep for all the comment "ups" I gave him though?

Comment: @Jess - comment upvotes do not count towards reputation points.

Answer (score 3):

Each function only knows it local variables (and globals, which you don't have any defined).  You have to create a variable for the result from in main:

```
int main()
{
   double answer = factorial();
   cout << answer << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

I don't know if you care, but the factorial value is going to overflow.

Comment: it doesnt overflow the excution time comes out fine

Comment: The execution time will be fine (unless you have a painfully slow computer :-)), but the actual number calculated as the factorial "f" will overflow.

Comment: ah yes but the thing is if i used a small number like 10 its gives an excution time of zero so i had to use a big number ,, what do u think ??

Comment: Yeah, its fine if you are just trying to test the speed of your computer.

Comment: yes yes it has nothng to do with the factorial as a function iam just testing any function

Comment: :-) -- I just added that he should upvote your answer as well; if he went to the trouble of creating a profile, then it will help his rep grow too.  I feel like a little kid trying to a 1,000 :)

Answer (score 3):

Because T1 is not defined under the main() scope, it is only defined under the scope of your function *factorial*.

You should do this instead:

```
cout<<factorial()<<endl;
```

or define T1 like this within your *main* function:

```
double T1 = factorial();
cout<<T1<<endl;
```

Comment: is it normal that the answer changes a little bit,, is it somethng to do with the clock cycles

Comment: well since T1's value depends on the values returned by "clock", then I'd suspect that the result would change on every program's execution.